# Turn off Ubuntu 23.10 window capture / gluing functionality

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 23.10

Is there any way to turn off the window capture / gluing functionality in Ubuntu 23.10?

What I mean is best demonstrated taking any window (i.e. Chrome Browser) and pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> +  and then taking a second window (i.e. Writer) and pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + . The two windows should now be glued together in the middle, hence changing the width of one window will automatically affect the other one it is glued to.

While this looks like good functionality at first glance, it is quite annoying in real-life. Taking a third window (i.e. Terminal) and pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> +  will not lock the third window to any of the other two windows. So now the two visible windows will be Chrome Browser on the left and Terminal on the right, though when clicking on Chrome Browser the Writer becomes visible, because it still is glued to Chrome Browser. Hence, Terminal just was pushed to the back and is not visible anymore.

How can I turn this window capture / gluing functionality off?

Answer (score 1):

In the settings, navigate to "Ubuntu Desktop", at the bottom "Enhanced Tiling", and disable "Tile Groups".